# Using Java Spark Load Existing Mongodb to Hive

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

**Goal**

I am working on ETL Mongodb to Hive using Spark (2.3.1) with Java

**Where I am RN**

I can load existing Mongodb and show/query the data

**Problem**

but I have issue saving it to hive table.

**Mongodb data structure**

Current mongodb data is complicate nested dict (struct type), is there a way to transform to save in hive more easily?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // spark session read mongodb
    SparkSession mongo_spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
            .config("mongo_spark.master", "local")
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db.test_collection")
            .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db.test_collection")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();

    // Create a JavaSparkContext using the SparkSession's SparkContext object
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(mongo_spark.sparkContext());

    // Load data and infer schema, disregard toDF() name as it returns Dataset
    Dataset<Row> implicitDS = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
    implicitDS.printSchema();
    implicitDS.show();

    // createOrReplaceTempView
    implicitDS.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table");
    // mongo_spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table");
    // cannot save table this step
    // implicitDS.write().saveAsTable("my_table");
    // can query the temp view
    mongo_spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table limit 1").show();

    // More application logic would go here...
    JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
    System.out.println(rdd.count());
    System.out.println(rdd.first().toJson());

    jsc.close();
}
```

Does anyone have experience in doing this ETL spark job in Java?
I really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `MongoSpark.load(jsc)` twice? Why is the input and output URI the same collection? What's the issue with Hive? Hive also supports nested data

Comment: Some code just for my testing, to see if I could read the data. Do you know what should I do to save hive table from mongodb?

Comment: `sqlContext.saveAsTable()`?

Comment: is there a way to create a hive table using existing mongodb schema?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE name AS SELECT fields FROM mongoTable` ... ?

Comment: Do you have a example code that load mongodb and save to a hive table, say only simple data like id, name, score

Comment: I do not. Never really used Mongo. But what's wrong with a `mongo_spark.sql` statement with the code I gave?

Comment: somehow the schema is not picked up by reading the fields. I really appreciate you reply to my questions. I thought read from mongodb and save to hive should be a common demand but I could not find example code so far...

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include `implicitDS.printSchema()` output?

Comment: Mongo isn't the problem. You have a DataSet. Thats it. Forget where it came from. I don't understand why this does not work for you - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#saveAsTable-java.lang.String-

Comment: I solved a dependency issue for json4s, and then I found this issue "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported data type NullType", seems null data in my original table, finding a way to work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As worked more about it, I realized this is a broad question. The precise answer to this question is

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // spark session read mongodb
    SparkSession mongo_spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
            .config("mongo_spark.master", "local")
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db.test_collection")
            .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db.test_collection")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();

    // Create a JavaSparkContext using the SparkSession's SparkContext object
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(mongo_spark.sparkContext());

    // Load data and infer schema, disregard toDF() name as it returns Dataset
    Dataset<Row> implicitDS = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
    implicitDS.printSchema();
    implicitDS.show();

    // createOrReplaceTempView
    implicitDS.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table");
    mongo_spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table");
    implicitDS.write().saveAsTable("my_table");

    jsc.close();
}
```

So that actually the code is working but what blocks me is that something happening in my data

1. conflict data type of single field (com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast…) - this can be resolve increasing the sample size while loading, check java syntax
   [How to config Java Spark sparksession samplesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004914/how-to-config-java-spark-sparksession-samplesize)
2. nulltype in nested structure - this one I am still seeking a solution in Java

As many research I got scala code samples, I'll do my best to record what I found and hopefully it can save your time one day