# How to config Java Spark sparksession samplesize

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Java Spark.

I am currently have issue with Mongodb ETL to hive, that could cause the field have different data type. So that I want to increase the sample size but I only see examples of scala while I am using Java, does anyone know if I setup to increase samplesize properly?

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local[2]")
                .appName("SparkReadMgToHive")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test.testcollection")
                .config("sampleSize", 50000)
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `spark.mongodb.input.sampleSize`

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local[2]")
                .appName("SparkReadMgToHive")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test.testcollection")
                .config("spark.mongodb.input.sampleSize", 50000)
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: Thank you I think it worked, I have another question posted, if you have clue please share your thoughts, I am very much appreciate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965429/how-to-resolve-com-mongodb-spark-exceptions-mongotypeconversionexception-cannot